# AS3 project conversion into Javascript/Html

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

Is there any programmer available to convert my AS3 project with external Actionscript files into Javascript/Html5?

Sorry for posting this here but I cant contact any programmer in here via private message so if anyone interesting please leave an email or contact me.

Thanks in advance.

PS: If I am posting to wrong place please administrators move it to the correct place or inform me how to contact any programmer.

Comment: **(1)** No one can contact you because you have no contact details (in your profile's "About" section). **(2)** No indication of the level or amount of work involved (is it a game with 100 levels coded in the AS files?, or just a basic tool that happens to hold simple functions in those external AS files?). **(3)** Your question will likely be closed soon (because there is no issue with code itself)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a solicitation for work, not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert [as3 into Haxe](https://github.com/innogames/ax3), which supports many targets such as native, html5, mobile, etc.